# How can I fetch all the elements in A but not in B?

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, how can I fetch all the element in `A` but not in `B`?

If

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8];
B = [1 2 3];
```

I hope the answer to be `[4 5 6 7 8]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you need [`setdiff()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html).

Answer (score 4):

As Oli stated you can use setdiff, however a little faster way to perform the same operation is

```
C = A(~ismember(A, B));
```

setdiff also sorts the resulting array, if you need this you have to sort C in the above statement

Comment: `setdiff` takes an optional argument `'stable'` to leave the output in the original order.